# Which is correct, singular or plural? "interval $(-2, 0)\cup(2, \infty)$" vs "intervals $(-2, 0)\cup(2, \infty)$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, interval-arithmetic

I am interested in understanding the correct grammar for the use of the term "interval" vs. "intervals" (plural).

For example: which of these is correctly stated?

- A polynomial $p(x)>0$ on the **interval** $(-2, 0)\cup(2, \infty)$
- A polynomial $p(x)>0$ on the **intervals** $(-2, 0)\cup(2, \infty)$

I understand that the union of two intervals is *not* nessarily an interval (can be proven by counterexample because the intersection of two intervals may be an empty set).

That being the case, it seems that when defining the solution set to an inequality using interval notation the use of "intervals" is more appropriate than "interval."  But, I have seen both statements.  Which is correct?

Comment: Both are wrong. You should say 'on the intervals $(-2,0)$ and $(2,\infty)$'.

Comment: To amplify the comment by @Kavi Rama Murthy, the singular "interval" is wrong because, as you noticed, that union is not an interval. The plural "intervals" is also wrong because that union is just one set, not two (or more). The plural becomes correct if you say "and" instead of "$\cup$", because then you have two sets and they are intervals.

Comment: Thank you, your justification is clear and intuitive!